# How to hide parameter in Angularjs working inside ng-bind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using Angular to form the final URL here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">

<p>Input the offer information your need to fill:</p>
<p>Adjust tracking link: <input type="text" ng-model="url"></p>
<p>Campaign: <input type="text" ng-model="campaign"></p>
<p>Adjust event token 1: <input type="text" ng-model="event1">Mobile goal id 1: <input type="text" ng-model="clickid1"></p>

<textarea style="width:600px; height:300px;" ng-bind="'http://' + url + '?campaign=' + campaign + '&event_callback_' + event1 + '=' + 'http://wavogo.go2cloud.org/aff_goal?a=lsr&goal_id=' + clickid1 + '&transaction_id={transaction_id}'"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mx8o1ttq/

How to hide campaign parameter from the string if it wasn't entered in the input?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to hide the campaign parameter from the url?

Comment: Yes, in textarea below. And show it only when it's filled with any value.

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: below are few answers, mark as correct if you found any answer solving your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can watch campaign model and manage your `'?campaign=' + campaign` via new model (`campaignWithText` for example).

```
$scope.$watch('campaign', function() {
      if($scope.campaign.length > 0 )
        $scope.campaignWithText = '?campaign=' + $scope.campaign;
      else
        $scope.campaignWithText = '';   
});
```

and change your textarea:

```
<textarea style="width:600px; height:300px;" ng-bind="'http://' + url + campaignWithText + '&event_callback_' + event1 + '=' + 'http://wavogo.go2cloud.org/aff_goal?a=lsr&goal_id=' + clickid1 + '&transaction_id={transaction_id}'"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ms403Ly8/128/

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer to do this kind of checks in `controller`.

You can do this by two ways:

```
($scope.campaign ? '?campaign=' + $scope.campaign : '')
```

or

```
($scope.campaign && '?campaign=' + $scope.campaign || '')
```

Then, in **controller**:

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.getContent = function() {
    return 'http://' + $scope.url + ($scope.campaign && '?campaign=' + $scope.campaign || '') + '&event_callback_' + $scope.event1 + '=' + 'http://wavogo.go2cloud.org/aff_goal?a=lsr&goal_id=' + $scope.clickid1 + '&transaction_id={transaction_id}';
  }
}
```

Finally, in your **view**:

```
<textarea style="width:600px; height:300px;" ng-bind="getContent()"></textarea>
```

Comment: i too prefer this answer on top of all the answers provided.

Answer (score 0):

I just initialise a variable called url with 'campaign' if the text box is filled with some string. But if the textbox is empty initialise variable url with an empty string.

```
<textarea style="width:600px; height:300px;" ng-init="url = campaign ?'campaign':''" ng-bind="'http://' + url + '?' +url + "=" + campaign + '&event_callback_' + event1 + '=' + 'http://wavogo.go2cloud.org/aff_goal?a=lsr&goal_id=' + clickid1 + '&transaction_id={transaction_id}'"/>
```